# Magento Adding Step to Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm attempting to add a very basic (literally just a div with some text and a continue button) step to the onepage checkout but have come up short, in that they don't work (i suspect it's because they were created prior to 1.7.0.2), when following the examples [here (Fontis)](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/adding-step-onepage-checkout), [here (inchoo)](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-a-new-tab-under-one-page-checkout-full-working-module/) and [here (Magento Forums)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6775/).

I've also tried to combined bits from different examples and forum posts but i've gotten no where in the week i've been attempting to do this.

I have been recommended the book 'Php Architect's Guide to E-Commerce Programming with Magento' which i've purchased and will begin reading but i was wondering if someone could kindly point me in the right direction in adding a new step to 1.7.0.2's onepage checkout?

Much appreciated for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done this successfully in 1.7.0.2 following this guide:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step

In summary, you need to extend/override Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage::getSteps() to add your new step in the sequence.

Create your new step's block/template (loaded using an Ajax request when the previous step is completed) Your block class will need to extend: Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract

You also need to extend the onepagecheckout javascript as this does much of the heavy lifting. The Prototype library has a nice way of doing this.

Finally you will need to extend the controller class (Mage_Checkout_OnepageController) to override the responses of any existing steps, return the content of your new step (loaded using ajax), and handle the save action of any data (form fields etc) entered in your new step.

Answer (score 2):

By default magento gives some checkout steps. But Sometime you need to add extra information from the customer for future reference. A common requested customization is to add the Custom Form in default checkout process.
This is not good practice to touch core files. You can do this via overriding Modules.
In this example Comapnyname is **Ipragmatech** and Module name is **Checkoutstep**.

Step1: Add Custom step in the checkout process

Open the Ipragmatech > Checkoutstep > Block > Onepage> Checkoutstep.php file and write the following code

```
    class Ipragmatech_Checkoutstep_Block_Onepage_Checkoutstep extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
    {
       protected function _construct()
       {     
          $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('checkoutstep', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Invitation to participation'),
          'is_show'   => true
        ));
        parent::_construct();
       }
     }
```

Step2: Add steps which and where you want in the checkout process

Open the Ipragmatech > Checkoutstep > Block > Onepage> Checkoutstep.php file and write the following code

```
    class Ipragmatech_Checkoutstep_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
    {
      public function getSteps()
      {
             $steps = array();

             if (!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
                $steps['login'] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData('login');
             }

            $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'checkoutstep', 'review');
         foreach ($stepCodes as $step) {
             $steps[$step] = $this->getCheckout()->getStepData($step);
          }

    return $steps;
   }
}
```

Step3: Grab the submitted value of custom form and set the values of Custom form

Open the ipragmatech > Checkoutstep > controllers > OnepageController.php and write the following fucntion

```
    public function saveCheckoutstepAction()
    {
      $this->_expireAjax();
      if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

     //Grab the submited value 
     $_entrant_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('entrant_name',"");
     $_entrant_phone = $this->getRequest()->getPost('entrant_phone',"");
     $_entrant_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('entrant_email',"");
     $_permanent_address = $this->getRequest() ->getPost('permanent_address',"");
     $_address = $this->getRequest()->getPost('local_address',"");

     Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->setIpragmatechCheckoutstep(serialize(array(
    'entrant_name' =>$_entrant_name,
    'entrant_phone' =>$_entrant_phone,
    'entrant_email' =>$_entrant_email,
    'permanent_address' =>$_permanent_address,
    'address' =>$_address
     )));

    $result = array();
    $redirectUrl = $this->getOnePage()->getQuote()->getPayment() ->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
        if (!$redirectUrl) {
            $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
            $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'review',
                'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
            );

        }

        if ($redirectUrl) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
    }
}
```

Step4: Save Custom Form information

When checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
event hook is called. Open the Ipragmatech > Checkoutstep > Model >Observer.php and write the following

```
    class Ipragmatech_Checkoutstep_Model_Observer {
      const ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_FHC_ID = 'checkoutstep';
      public function hookToOrderSaveEvent() {
      if (Mage::helper('checkoutstep')->isEnabled()) {
         $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order ();
         $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton ( 'checkout/session' )->getLastRealOrderId ();
         $order->loadByIncrementId ( $incrementId );

       // Fetch the data 
       $_checkoutstep_data = null;
       $_checkoutstep_data = Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session' )->getIpragmatechCheckoutstep ();
       $model = Mage::getModel ( 'checkoutstep/customerdata' )->setData ( unserialize ( $_checkoutstep_data ) );
       $model->setData ( "order_id",$order["entity_id"] );
       try {
           $insertId = $model->save ()->getId ();
             Mage::log ( "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: " . $insertId, null, 'mylog.log');
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            Mage::log ( "EXCEPTION " . $e->getMessage (), null, 'mylog.log' );
          }
        }
    }
```

}

Magento – Add Custom Form in Checkout Extension is a complete solution to add extra step in Checkout process for your ecommerce website. It allow admin to export data from custom table in CSV format.
Visit the link to get this free extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-form-in-checkout.html